# Implement simple quiescence search algorithm

Tags: python, negamax

I'm trying to implement a simple quiescence search for my negamax AI (not chess - 10-10-5 mnk or gomoku style game called Take 5). It already has a transposition table.
The main negamax algorithm looks like this:

```
def negamax(board, depth, alpha, beta, player, ttable):
    if board in ttable:
        value, vtype = ttable[board]
        if vtype == 0:
            return value
        elif vtype == 1:
            beta = min(alpha, value)
        else:
            alpha = max(beta, value)
    score = board.getValue()
    if abs(score) == 1000000000000:
        return player * score
    if depth == 0:
        return player * score
    oldAlpha = alpha
    possibleMoves = board.getBestNextMoves()
    value = -1000000000000
    for move in possibleMoves:
        #child = board#Board(board)
        board.place(move, player)
        value = max(value, -negamax(board, depth-1, -beta, -alpha,
                                    -player, ttable))
        board.place(move, 0)
        alpha = max(alpha, value)
        if alpha >= beta:
            break # alpha beta prune
    if value <= oldAlpha:
        vtype = 1
    elif value >= beta:
        vtype = -1
    else:
        vtype = 0
    ttable[board] = (value, vtype)
    return value
```

I've looked online for some quiescence search algorithms, but they seem to not work properly, but this is what I've come up with:

```
def quiesce(board, alpha, beta, player, ttable):
if board in ttable:
    value, vtype = ttable[board]
    if vtype == 0:
        score = value
    else:
        score = player * board.getValue()
        ttable[board] = (score, 0)
else:
    score = board.getValue()
    ttable[board] = (score, 0)
if score >= beta:
    return score
if alpha < score:
    alpha = score
for move in board.getForcedMoves(player):
    board.place(move, player)
    score = -quiesce(board, -beta, -alpha, -player, ttable)
    board.place(move, 0)
    if score >= beta:
        return score
    if score > alpha:
        alpha = score
return alpha
```

Can you check that I have implemented properly a quiescence search for this algorithm?

Comment: accidentally posted the question before I was done making it, it is ready now

Comment: It seems you know the algorithm and you implement it by yourself. So can not you run it on your laptop to see if it works or not ?

Comment: @codrelphi it appears to work, however that does not mean that it works 100% correctly

Comment: for example, min-max may try to minimize the score for the wrong player, but if when you search through and pick the move with the best evaluation, it will appear to play good moves

Comment: Ok. It is better to post your code in the code review section: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not fussed about coding styles, just the algorithm, does that fit with the style of question on codereview?

Comment: @codrelphi "Code Review is for open-ended questions about code that already works correctly" In this case, that is under question